# Blank UITableView after iAd

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have two `UITableViews` with an `ADBannerView` on the bottom of each one.  When I tap the ad on the first view then exit the ad, the `TableView` returns.  However, when I tap the ad on the second view then exit, both the iAd and the `TableView` are missing.  The `navigation bar` (implemented without a `navigation controller`) is still there.  If I call:

```
- (void)bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    [self.assignmentTableView reloadData];
}
```

The `TableView` is still blank.  What is going on?

Comment: you need to provide more information than that. Are both tables in one UIViewcontroller ? how do you transition back and forth from ad view ?

Comment: The two tables are in separate ViewControllers, connected by a modal segue called when a cell in the first VC is tapped.  I transition back and forth from the ADBannerView by tapping the ADBannerView in the bottom of each VC, then exit the iAd by tapping the 'x' in the top-left corner.

Answer (score 0):

The ADBannerView delegate must not be set.

If that doesn't work, try placing `[self.assignmentTableView reloadData];` in your `viewWillAppear` method.